# Não consigo incorporar um vídeo do YouTube ao meu site

Tags: html, css

Estou inserindo o seguinte código de iframe para incorporar um vídeo do YouTube, mas o código não gera o vídeo no site, o que estou errando?

EU peguei essa parte do código em um código que vi e apenas mudei o l

Aparece somente uma borda cinza, mas o vídeo não fica disponível no site.

**código:**

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvPo7JUAP8k"> </iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

o valor do atributo src está errado, pois o link que está é o de visualização do vídeo, o link de incorporação é diferente para incorpora-lo,vocẽ deve entrar no video desejado e clicar em compartilhar logo em seguida em incorporar o link e o código html ja séra gerado

Answer (score 3):

O formato correto do `src` é como abaixo:

> https://www.youtube.com/embed/ + código do vídeo

No seu caso, ficaria assim:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dvPo7JUAP8k"> </iframe>
```